# Generic repository filter data of T

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a generic repository and i want to filter the data on Get in the generic repository. This method get the data and then other get methods call and return data

```
private IQueryable<T> fetchData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null) query = query.Where(filter);
}
```

This is the DbSet

```
private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;
```

and the class implemention is

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

These are the classes and interfaces on Model class

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
public interface IAuditableEntity
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
public abstract class AuditableEntity : Entity<string>, IEntity<string>, IAuditableEntity
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
[Table("Contact")]
public class Contact : AuditableEntity
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to filter the data in `fetchData` method so that only those records return which are `deleted == false` as this is a common functionality and should be implemented in repository base level not on individual repository or business logic classes.

The problem is that once i cast `IQueryable<T> query` to `IQueryable<IAuditableEntity> query` i cannot convert it back to IQueryable or for further filteration of data and return. I tried these but didn't work

```
var dbSetIAuditableEntity = dbSet as IQueryable<AuditableEntity>;

if (dbSetIAuditableEntity != null)
{
    dbSetIAuditableEntity = dbSetIAuditableEntity.Where(d => d.IsDeleted == false);
    query = (IQueryable<T>)((object)dbSetIAuditableEntity);

    query = dbSet.Where(d => ((IAuditableEntity)d).IsDeleted == false);
}
```

Any suggestions to implement this functionality is generic repository

**Edit**

Actually all entities don't implement `AuditableEntity` some implement only `IEntity<String>` OR `IEntity<int>` and some implement nothing. It's not very good approach but this is the situation.

**Edit 2**

This is how i instantiate Generic repository By `Autofac`

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support this for all entities, then you'll need to constrain `T` to `AuditableEntity`:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
    where T : AuditableEntity
{
}
```

Otherwise, if not *all* entities can be constrained like that, derive from the `Repository<T>` and constrain that one:

```
public class AuditableRepository<T> : Repository<T> 
    where T : AuditableEntity
{
}
```

Comment: Your solution is what i've done previously but all entities don't implement `AuditableEntity` some implement only IEntity<String> and some implement nothing. It's not very good but this is the situation

Comment: Yeah but you're the only one who knows how you instantiate this repository. For the entities inheriting from AuditableEntity you use AuditableRepository, and otherwise just the base repository that doesn't do the deleted filtering.

Comment: I don't want to create any more repository class as it would be a big change in existing code and i have to do some major refactoring. That's why i want to do this in existing `Repository<T>`